# How do I provide bank statements from multiple accounts when applying for a New Zealand visa online?

Tags: visas, legal, new-zealand

I am a vietnamese, have stable job at a well-known bank in here and plans to apply a New Zealand visitor visa in february next year. I have done some research on how to apply it online and it got to this point now.

I have multiple bank accounts for different purposes, how can i present it in this part?

[image: This is the part where they asked to show bank statements.]

My accounts are:

Account 1 - Savings Account

This is where my savings is.

Account 2 - Payroll Account

This is where i receive payments from my full-time job. I also have some balance here.

Account 3 - Everyday Transactions account

This account is used for everyday transactions (food, utilities, bills, etc.). I dont keep any balance in here.

Is it okay to merge all three of my bank account statements in one file? Or is it better to submit only my saving accounts there, and present the other two as "other financial informations"?

Comment: Be aware that New Zealand's borders are closed to almost all travellers except citizens and permanent residents. This situation looks like it will continue for some time yet, possibly well beyond February.

Comment: I understand, i will go  there on august but will apply for the visa in february

Answer (score 1):

If you have sufficient funds in one of your accounts, you can just present that statement and it should work.
Now, if you want to present the three of them anyway and put them all into a single pdf, you won't ave any problem with it.

Comment: The OP should also present the payroll account proving receipt of salary

Comment: I have more than enough funds in account 1. However i rarely use this for transaction since this is made to deposit my monthly savings, so there are not a lot of expenditures in it.
However i think i will go with your suggestion to present the three of them anyway and merge them all into a single pdf. Thank you very much

Comment: @Ninh299202 what's important, you must to present them translated to English. In the very unlikely case they asked you to show evidence of funds and they think it's not proof enough, be prepared with your credit card to display an online statement in any ATM.

Comment: @AlterLagos I have debit card for each of my accounts therefore im not worried about credit cards.